# django-celery as a systemd service in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, systemd

Is this possible to daemonize django-celery as a systemd service for a project in virtualenv?

Here is my config:

/etc/systemd/system/celery.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant
Restart=no
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant/myproj/
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/var/www/vhost/myproj_env/bin/python \ 
   /vagrant/myproj/manage.py celery worker \ 
   --loglevel=DEBUG \
   --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log \ 
   --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker.pid \
   -Q availability,celery --time-limit=300'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/var/www/vhost/myproj_env/bin/python \ 
    /vagrant/myproj/manage.py celery stop \
   --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker.pid'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

all the directories mentioned here do exist, and the permissions set correctly

django-celery in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'djcelery',
    'celery_haystack',
    ...
)

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL
CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 30
```

The following command starts celery normally, and I can see tasks being executed:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -Q availability,celery
```

Which is basically the same as specified in the service conf, except it posts to stdout

However, when i try to `systemctl start celery.service`, it just fails silently: `systemctl status celery.service` reports inactive (dead)

I'd be thankful for any hint on this problem. I might be missing something obvious, though i have a feeling that the process should not be so complicated, as it it now ((

**UPDATE**

The celery logs tell, that celery starts normally, but for some reason sysctl doesn't accept it. Here is a snippet from the celery log with --loglevel=DEBUG:

```
[2017-07-09 21:55:09,435: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2017-07-09 21:55:09,439: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2017-07-09 21:55:09,439: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Beat, Timer, Hub, Queues (intra), Pool, Autoreloader, StateDB, Autoscaler, Consumer}
...
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,696: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,696: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,697: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,697: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,697: WARNING/MainProcess] /var/www/vhost/myproj_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:130: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,698: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@vagrant ready.
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,698: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2017-07-09 21:55:10,699: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->4
```

It is even processing tasks in the queue!

But after 30 seconds or so sysctl fails to understand that worker is actually functioning normally, and closes it:

```
Job for celery.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status celery.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo systemctl status celery.service
● celery.service - Celery Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2017-07-09 21:56:38 UTC; 3min 0s ago
  Process: 3139 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /var/www/vhost/myproj_env/bin/python /vagrant/myproj/manage.py c
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 47.4M
      CPU: 1.532s

Jul 09 21:55:08 vagrant systemd[1]: Starting Celery Service...
Jul 09 21:56:38 vagrant systemd[1]: celery.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 09 21:56:38 vagrant systemd[1]: Failed to start Celery Service.
Jul 09 21:56:38 vagrant systemd[1]: celery.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 09 21:56:38 vagrant systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

NB: I have reduced num of workers to one for simplicity, and edited conf files. This made the problem a bit clearer (it isn't a problem in celery, but probably in systemd), but still i have no clue, what's causing this timeout..

Comment: Can you try to get more logs from `sudo journalctl -u celery.service` ?

Comment: thanks for having a look, i've updated the description with log details

Comment: I would check the `${CELERY_LOG_FILE}` there will be some hints why the workers are killed after start...

Comment: i did.. celery functions normally (pls, see update). Still it is mystery what causes sysctl timeout..

Comment: got it, sorry for this confusion

Answer (score 8):

managed to fix it by removing `Type=forking` from **/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

Comment: It's odd, because it is working for me. However, I had this option enabled for my celery beat and it didn't work with it, I had to remove it.

Comment: @DanLupascu it's been a while ago, so, i don't remember all the details, but i the solution i've posted here, worked back then. nowadays i primarily use docker for deployment, so i rarely touch systemd